# TypeError: 'numpy.int64' object is not callable, whenever I call len function in python?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

whenever I try to use len function in my code I get this error ?

```
long_trade={}
short_trade={}
long_trade['total_long']=get_total_long(long_df,len(long_df))
short_trade['total_short']=get_total_short(short_df,len(short_df))

print(short_trade)
print(long_trade)
```

Error

```
> TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call
> last) <ipython-input-37-619a2cc53415> in <module>()
>       2 long_trade={}
>       3 short_trade={}
> ----> 4 long_trade['total_long']=get_total_long(long_df,len(long_df))
>       5 short_trade['total_short']=get_total_short(short_df,len(short_df))
>       6 
> 
> TypeError: 'numpy.int64' object is not callable
```

Comment: You're going to have to provide more code for us to be able to reproduce or solve your problem. But from the look of it, it looks like you named a variable `len` somewhere.

Comment: Please provide the expected [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  Show where the intermediate results deviate from the ones you expect.  We should be able to paste a single block of your code into file, run it, and reproduce your problem.

Comment: Sorry I cannot reproduce some part of the code. Due to Non-disclosure 

Answer (score 2):

One between `get_total_long` or `len` has been accidentally assigned to an integer, whether you think they should both be functions, hence you are calling them (by using parenthesis)

It's very likely that in your code you have somewhere a line like this:

`len = some expression which returns a numpy.int64`

or

`get_total_long = some expression which returns a numpy.int64`